# Difference between main.php and main-local.php in the config folder?

Tags: yii2

Can anyone please explain the difference between **main.php** and **main-local.php** in the config folder?

Why one has the **-local**, and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 13):

You can read [Configuration and environments](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-environments.md) section of [Advanced Application Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md) README to understand this:

> Typically environment contains application bootstrap files such as
>   index.php and config files suffixed with -local.php. These are added
>   to .gitignore and never added to source code repository.
>
> In order to avoid duplication configurations are overriding each
>   other. For example, the frontend reads configuration in the following
>   order:
>
> ```
> common/config/main.php
> common/config/main-local.php
> frontend/config/main.php
> frontend/config/main-local.php
> ```
>
> Parameters are read in the following order:
>
> ```
> common/config/params.php
> common/config/params-local.php
> frontend/config/params.php
> frontend/config/params-local.php
> ```
>
> The later config file overrides the former.

Comment: @user3265427 Updated both links

Comment: It seems that two config files (`main.php` and `main-local.php`) only makes sense if there are environments where one is used, but not the other. The documentation suggests that this setup can be used by larger development teams. But if each environment uses both config files, it makes more sense to merge them into one config file...

Comment: so how can I access main.php data from the app? I can see only params.php in 'Yii::$app->params'